# Is there a way to get profile during runtime of a java application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am running a jar file and I use -Dspring.profiles.active=. How do I get the running profile name during runtime. I want to use that in my code and have some changes based on the profile. Is there any way to get that?

Comment: How do I get the run configuration during runtime?

Answer (score 5):

You need to inject `Environment` [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) into your class, e.g.:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
```

You can then call `getActiveProfiles()` method to get the profiles (documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html#getActiveProfiles--)). This is what the docs says:

> Returns the set of profiles explicitly made active for this
>   environment. Profiles are used for creating logical groupings of bean
>   definitions to be registered conditionally, for example based on
>   deployment environment. Profiles can be activated by setting
>   "spring.profiles.active" as a system property or by calling
>   ConfigurableEnvironment.setActiveProfiles(String...).

Also, `Environment` bean is created by Spring so you don't need to `@Bean` it explicitly in your application.

Comment: Thank you @Darshan. Got it .
For default profile it is  
@Value("${spring.profiles.active:default}")
private String activeProfile;

It worked now as expected